# Creating dataset outputs..where to start with this one?

Tags: sorting, report, sas, datastep

The variables in the data set are: `Event, EventType, FName, LName, Age, Gender, Score`.

I am trying to create a report that gives me the Lowest 5 scores per event/event type per each Age(18-65) per Gender.

For example, I want the 5 lowest scores for everyone who participated in EventA EventtypeB who were 18 year old females then I want all the 19 year old females and so on.. For each gender. A side note- Not all ages have 5 participants.. For example there may be no 20 year olds who participated and there may only be 2 21 year olds.

I originally tried to tackle this by making a bunch of separate data sets for each age, but I know there must be a better way to do it. I would appreciate any help thank you I am pretty new to SAS but I have introductory experience in all aspects.

Here is some sample input:
`Mile Sprint John Smith 19 Male 15.31`
`Mile Sprint Alex Doe   19 Male 13.21` 
`Mile Sprint Ian Sore   19 Male 23.51` 
`Mile Sprint Sean Lae   19 Male 12.34` 
`Mile Sprint Mike Rai   19 Male 17.27` 
`Mile Sprint Connor Te  19 Male 11.23` 
`Mile Sprint Simon Doe  19 Male 15.21` 
`Mile Long   Jane Joy   37 Female 35.12` 
`Mile Long   Victoria K 37 Female 27.31` 
`Mile Long  Chris Li  25 Male  23.43`

For the `Mile Sprint 19 Males` I would want it to return: 
`Mile Sprint Connor Te  19 Male 11.23` 
`Mile Sprint Sean Lae   19 Male 12.34` 
`Mile Sprint Alex Doe   19 Male 13.21` 
`Mile Sprint Simon Doe  19 Male 15.21` 
`Mile Sprint John Smith 19 Male 15.31`

For the `Mile Long 37 Female` I would want it to just return this due to there not being 5 participants: 
`Mile Long   Victoria K 37 Female 27.31` 
`Mile Long   Jane Joy   37 Female 35.12`

With the sample input shown I am trying to get the 5 lowest scores for `Mile Sprint` for Males age 19. Then the same for age 20-65. Then the same for `Mile Long` for all males. Vice versa for females. With the assumption that there may not be 5 participants in a race or there may be more than 5. Is there anyway to do all of this in one or two dataset outputs?

Comment: What do you mean by "creating a report" ? It seems you only need dataset outputs for lowest five scores group by event, age and gender.

Comment: You are right. That's what I meant. I'm sorry for my poor wording.

Comment: Adding sample input is always helpful and helps in answering the query faster!

Comment: Thanks! I added some sample input and some clarifications

Comment: Looking at the sample dataset, I suppose all of them would qualify for the desired output

Comment: I added more inputs and put a desired output for further clarification. thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/*    Creating Sample dataset */

```
    data input_dataset;
    infile datalines dlm=",";
    input Event : $10.
          EventType : $ 10.
          FName : $10.
          LName : $10.
          Age  : 8.
          Gender : $10.
          Score : 8.
          ;
    datalines;
    Mile,Sprint,John,Smith,19,Male,15.31
    Mile,Sprint,Alex,Doe,19,Male,13.21
    Mile,Sprint,Ian,Sore,19,Male,23.51
    Mile,Sprint,Sean,Lae,19,Male,12.34
    Mile,Sprint,Mike,Rai,19,Male,17.27
    Mile,Sprint,Connor,Te,19,Male,11.23
    Mile,Sprint,Simon,Doe,19,Male,15.21
    Mile,Long,Jane,Joy,37,Female,35.12
    Mile,Long,Victoria,K,37,Female,27.31
    Mile,Long,Chris,Li,25,Male,23.43
    ;
    run;
```

/* Sorting based on desired parameters - event EventType age Gender */

```
proc sort data =  input_dataset;
by event EventType age Gender score;
run;
```

/*Picking the lowest five scores based on above parameters */

```
data input_dataset_1(drop=num);
set input_dataset;
retain num;
by event EventType age Gender score;
if first.gender then num=1 ; else num=num+1;
if num<=5;
run;
```